# Possibility of regular surface with specific first and second fundamental form matrices

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

I have met this in diff. geometry class which states:

> We are to determine if there exists a regular surface in $ R^3 $, $ S = f(u,v) $ with fundamental forms as follows:
>
> $ I = \begin{bmatrix}
>     cos^2(u)       & 0 \\
>     0       & 1  \\
> \end{bmatrix} $
>
> $ II = \begin{bmatrix}
>    1      & 0 \\
>     0       & cos^2(u)  \\
> \end{bmatrix} $

I know that if S is a compact surface this cannot happen because the Gaussian curvature satisfies $ K=-1 $ and for a compact surface at least one point has positive K but can a general regular surface in $ R^3 $ have these fundamental forms? Also obviously $ cos^2(u) \neq 0 $ as first fundamental form should be invertible. Thanks for the help

Comment: Does that satisfy the Gauss equation (did you check)?

Comment: @JohnMa : what might that be? I know a few things named Gauss equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least [two ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) to calculate the Gaussian Curvature, when $M$ is a regular surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$.

- By the second fundamental form: 
  $$ K = \frac{\det II}{\det I} = \frac{\cos^2 u}{\cos^2 u} = 1.$$
- By the first fundamental form alone (this equation holds when $F = 0$, there's another formula when $F\neq 0$):
  $$ K = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}} \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial u} \frac{G_u}{\sqrt{EG}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \frac{E_v}{\sqrt{EG}}\right) = 0$$

Thus such a surface do not exist.